# How to update field "type" for all documents in mongodb collection using python mongodb client library (pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb, type-conversion, pymongo

This is the last link to completing a majorly important data pipeline. We have the following newline delimited JSON, that we've exported from BigQuery into GCS, and then have downloaded locally:

```
{"name":"Terripins","fga":"42","fgm":"28","fgPct":0.67}
{"gameTime":"2019-01-12 12:00:00 UTC","gameDate":"2019-01-12","updated":"2019-01-12 20:25:03 UTC","isHome":true,"name":"","fga":"0","fgm":"0"}
{"gameTime":"2019-01-12 12:00:00 UTC","gameDate":"2019-01-12","updated":"2019-01-12 20:25:03 UTC","isHome":true,"name":"Crusaders","fga":"54","fgm":"33","fgPct":0.61}
{"gameTime":"2019-01-12 12:00:00 UTC","gameDate":"2019-01-12","updated":"2019-01-12 20:25:03 UTC","isHome":false,"name":"Greyhounds","fga":"54","fgm":"33","fgPct":0.61}
{"gameTime":"2019-01-12 12:00:00 UTC","gameDate":"2019-01-12","updated":"2019-01-12 20:25:03 UTC","isHome":false,"name":"Greyhounds","fga":"68","fgm":"20","fgPct":0.29}
{"gameTime":"2019-01-12 12:00:00 UTC","gameDate":"2019-01-12","updated":"2019-01-12 20:25:03 UTC","isHome":true,"name":"Crusaders","fga":"68","fgm":"20","fgPct":0.29}
```

We `mongoimport` this into our mongodb cluster, and the collection is successfully created:

[image]

Unfortunately, when we export the JSON from BigQuery, the integer types are converted into strings (see `fga`, `fgm`), and the date columns are also converted into strings. This image shows the original schema from BigQuery.

[image]

We are trying to use the python mongodb client library **pymongo** to convert `fga`, and `fgm` into integer types. Presumably it is easier to (a) load the "stringified" json file into mongodb, and then use pymongo to update types, rather than (b) update or fix the types directly in the JSON file **before** `mongoimport`ing into mongo. So we are trying (a).

```
import(pymongo)

... connect to db and set "db"
our_collection = db["our_coll_name"]

# query and set for "update"
myquery = {} # for whole table
newvalues = { "$set": { "fga": int(fga) } } # change to int

# and update
new_output = our_collection.update_many(myquery, newvalues)
print(new_output.modified_count, "documents updated."
```

This doesn't work because `int(fga)` returns an error `name 'fga' is not defined`, and if we instead run `int("fga")`, we get the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'fga'`.

These errors both make complete sense to us, but we're still unsure then of how to update `fga` and `fgm` in this example to `int`. Also, are there mongo-specific `date` and `timestamp` types we can use for the 3 fields `[gameTime, gameDate, updated]`, and how can we make these conversions as well using pymongo?

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming MongoDB 4.2 or later.**

Use MongoDB's `toInt()` and `toDate()` functions.

I've split these into seperate commands for clarity but you could run it in one update_many() if you prefer.

```
our_collection.update_many({}, [{'$set': {'fga': {'$toInt': '$fga'}}}])
our_collection.update_many({}, [{'$set': {'fgm': {'$toInt': '$fgm'}}}])
our_collection.update_many({}, [{'$set': {'gameTime': {'$toDate': '$gameTime'}}}])
our_collection.update_many({}, [{'$set': {'gameDate': {'$toDate': '$gameDate'}}}])
our_collection.update_many({}, [{'$set': {'updated': {'$toDate': '$updated'}}}])
```

Documentation:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

Comment: I think we have 4.0, although per the docs it seems like these work for version 4.0 as well - will give these a try shortly

Comment: Those operators are aggregation operators and will not work in an update operation.